# How can i add dynamically widget into a widget's layout in QT

Tags: c++, qt, layout

What i want to do is to add a widget in a widget's layout dynamically:

```
my_widget->layout()->addWidget(another_widget);
```

but sadly layout() method is an accessor.

Another way to do this is use the ui variable of the MainWindow,

```
ui->my_widget_layout->addWidget(another_widget);
```

which gives me direct access to widget's layout. 
Is there another way to do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: implement `addWwidget` as a member of your `my_widget`

Comment: Hello. layout() will still be an accessor. Also QWidget and QObject don't have any layout member variable. Even if i implement addWidget in MyWidget, i will still be unable to add new widgets to my_widget's layout. Thnx

Comment: then also make the layout a member, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's wrong about `layout()` being an accessor? It works! It returns `QLayout *`, and you can add other widgets to it. Make sure you `show()` these widgets if the parent is already visible.

You can also cast layouts, if you think being more specific would be useful in a particular layout:

```
auto *grid = qobject_cast<QGridLayout*>(parent->layout());
if (grid)
  // Add in the second column
  grid->addWidget(widget, grid->rowCount(), 1);
else
  parent->layout()->addWidget(widget);
widget->show();
```